# input placeholder is not showing

Tags: html, css, input, placeholder

the placeholder doesn't show up until I focus then unfocus the field.

```html
<input type="tel" name="natid" id="natid" class="form-control"    onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Hello'" required="" value="" maxlength="10" pattern="[0-9]{10}" style="width: 100%;height: 10vw;color: #000;font-weight: 400;font-size: 5vw;letter-spacing: 0.5em;">
```

Comment: Even if you don't write the onfocus event to clear the placeholder, by default once you start writing into inputbox, it automatically clears the placeholder

Comment: @MrunmayDeswandikar I needed it to go away before typing that why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you have written the part:

```
onblur="this.placeholder = 'Hello'"
```

Thus, placeholder will only be set only on the blur event

To explicitly set the placeholder use the placeholder property of input tag:

```
<input placeholder="Hello">
```

Answer (score 4):

Add a `placeholder="hello"` to your tag.

```html
<input type="tel" name="natid" id="natid" class="form-control" placeholder="Hello"    onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Hello'" required="" value="" maxlength="10" pattern="[0-9]{10}" style="width: 100%;height: 10vw;color: #000;font-weight: 400;font-size: 5vw;letter-spacing: 0.5em;">
```

Answer (score 1):

add one more attribute placeholder="Hello". so when the page loads then placeholder will show.

```
<input type="tel" name="natid" id="natid" class="form-control" placeholder="Hello"   onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder='Hello'" required="" value="" maxlength="10" pattern="[0-9]{10}" style="width: 100%;height: 10vw; color: #000; font-weight: 400; font-size: 5vw;letter-spacing: 0.5em;">
```